# Return Regex Matches from a sql query

Tags: sql-server, regex

I have a table that stores html templates which contain markup with placeholders in key locations, something like this ...

```
<div>
   <div>{FirstName}</div>
   <div>{LastName}</div>
</div>
```

I want to write a query that returns from the table all of the placeholders used from all rows.

```
SELECT Template 
FROM MyTable
WHERE ????
```

So for the above example the result I want is ...

```
{FirstName}
{LastName}
```

I have seen people using regex in SQL but can't figure out how to only return the matches and not the whole column value.
It's also worth noting that I want a result per match ideally but if I got a comma separated list per row that matched or something that would do.

Comment: Your matches are identified by {}, right? SQL Server or MySQL? You use both in your tags!

Comment: My bad, mysql removed.

Comment: I've provided the code. Do you understand it? Otherwise I'll provide further information.

Comment: So you want a regex to get `{FirstName} {LastName}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would approach this using a [numbers table](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/11506/7257), which are very useful anyway, so if you don't have one, I would consider creating one, but for the sake of a complete answer I will assume you don't have one and can't create one. In such scenarios you can generate a list of numbers on the fly quite easily using:

```
WITH N1 AS (SELECT N FROM (VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) n (N)),
N2 (N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM N1 AS N1 CROSS JOIN N1 AS N2),
N3 (N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM N2 AS N1 CROSS JOIN N2 AS N2),
--N4 (N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM N3 AS N1 CROSS JOIN N3 AS N2)
Numbers (Number) AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY N) FROM N3)

SELECT Number
FROM Numbers;
```

This starts with a table of 10 rows created with a [table value constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/dd776382.aspx) (N1), it then joins this table with itself to get a table of 100 rows (N2), then joins N2 to itself to get 10,000 rows (N3), this can be repeated as required, before finally using [`ROW_NUMBER()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms186734.aspx) to get a sequential number in each row. Aaron Bertrand has done a pretty comprehensive series on [generating a set or sequence without loops](http://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-1), and this method comes out on top (as a method of creating the table on the fly).

Once you have this numbers table you can join it to your template to find the position of each `"{"` using [`SUBSTRING`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx):

```
SELECT  t.Template,
        StartPosition = n.Number
FROM    dbo.T
        INNER JOIN Numbers n
            ON SUBSTRING(t.Template, n.Number, 1) = '{';
```

With your example this will return 16, and 43. Then you can use [`CHARINDEX`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms186323.aspx) to find the `"}"` that follows each `"{"`:

```
SELECT  t.Template,
        StartPosition = n.Number,
        EndPosition = CHARINDEX('}', t.template, n.Number) + 1
FROM    dbo.T
        INNER JOIN Numbers n
            ON SUBSTRING(t.Template, n.Number, 1) = '{';
```

Then you can use [`SUBSTRING`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx) again to extract the term between each start and end position. So a full working example would be:

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (Template NVARCHAR(MAX));
INSERT @T (Template)
VALUES ('<div>
   <div>{FirstName}</div>
   <div>{LastName}</div>
</div>');

WITH N1 AS (SELECT N FROM (VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) n (N)),
N2 (N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM N1 AS N1 CROSS JOIN N1 AS N2),
N3 (N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM N2 AS N1 CROSS JOIN N2 AS N2),
--N4 (N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM N3 AS N1 CROSS JOIN N3 AS N2)
Numbers (Number) AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY N) FROM N3)

SELECT  t.Template,
        StartPosition = n.Number,
        EndPosition = CHARINDEX('}', t.template, n.Number) + 1,
        Term = SUBSTRING(t.template, n.Number, CHARINDEX('}', t.template, n.Number) + 1 - n.Number)
FROM    @T t
        INNER JOIN Numbers n
            ON SUBSTRING(t.Template, n.Number, 1) = '{';
```

Comment: Thinking like a SQL guy definitely turns the world upside down ... this is impressive stuff, thanks :)

Comment: @ionic solution is a little easier to understand though so I'm gonna go with that one on this occasion.

Answer (score 1):

See this:

```
CREATE TABLE #temp(id int identity(1,1), template nvarchar(max))

INSERT INTO #temp(template)
SELECT REPLICATE(N'<div>
   <div>{FirstName}</div>
   <div>{LastName}</div>
</div>',1000)

;WITH cte AS(
    SELECT id, 
        SUBSTRING(template,CHARINDEX(N'{',template),CHARINDEX(N'}',template)-CHARINDEX(N'{',template)+1) as match,
        SUBSTRING(template,CHARINDEX(N'}',template)+1,LEN(template)) as templateRest
    FROM #temp
    UNION ALL
    SELECT id, 
        SUBSTRING(templateRest,CHARINDEX(N'{',templateRest),CHARINDEX(N'}',templateRest)-CHARINDEX(N'{',templateRest)+1) as match,
        SUBSTRING(templateRest,CHARINDEX(N'}',templateRest)+1,LEN(templateRest)) as templateRest
    FROM cte
    WHERE templateRest LIKE N'%}%'
)
SELECT t.id, t.template, c.match
-- Only distinctive:
-- SELECT DISTINCT t.id, t.template c.match
FROM cte AS c
INNER JOIN #temp AS t
        ON c.id = t.id
OPTION(MAXRECURSION 1000) -- if needed, this value could still be raised

DROP TABLE #temp
GO
```

You can filter it for the template and retrieve all matches.

Comment: No problem. Just one thing to mention. If your template has more than 100 template marker in it, this may abort. You can raise these Limit using the `MAX_RECURSION` option on your query. Just to mention this.

Comment: Ok did some testing, this doesn't actually work, it returns substring errors with my templates :(

Comment: This may depend on the template. Can you provide an example on which it happened?

Comment: The only thing which may force a substring error may be a incorrect template string ( first `}` then `{`) or a string without any template markers. Just for me, can you provide a string which fail? I'll try to adapt the answer.

Comment: these template strings are very long (8k), another problem with this solution that it can't handle, I believe they are all valid strings but they are "email html" which is "html from the 80's for compatibility reasons"

Comment: Well the html won't be a problem. The 8k may be a problem maybe, but as I tested it, I've used even longer strings for this and it worked. Mh.

Comment: The stuff function only accepts up to 4k ... I already tried to refactor your example defining the #temp with a ntext column and it blew up making a stuff call

Comment: Ah yes in this part i used stuff for compatibility versions. I see. :-) You can split it in 4000 chars. This was the attempt which I used on my dev system. :-) Do you still need it? In this case I would split it and provide an updated version.

Comment: Wouldn't you end up with 2 template parts thus resulting in the problem you mentioned before ... half a template means you could get broken { and } pairs.

Comment: No If you split them right not. It's quite easy. Seraching for the last `}`in a 4000 char string. Then make a cut. Use the rest of the string for the next subset.

Comment: so if my first { and my last } are less than 4k apart all good ... that's unlikely in my case, I think it would be easier to just select the indexes in to a table var then select from the original data by those indexes using substring ... in theory no need for stuff then.

Comment: Hi @Wardy, see the corrected script above. I tested it with a much longer string. It should work.